# Variable initialized once with dynamic value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, constants

I have declared a constant variable which is being stored in cookie so its Ok because differnt browser will have a different copy.

```
private const string CookieName = "TempData";
```

Now I want to store it at third location where all user data will be stored.

So How can I declare something like

private const string CookieName = "TempData" + DataTime.Now.Tick.tostring();
So that each user will have differnet cookiename stored at third location.

Please advise.

Comment: I just edited my answer (that was wrong), please have a look. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: You need to remove const keyword. Where this variable is declared? If you want to have different cookie for each user then why not create cookie with the username or unique id of the user itself. That would give you more control.

Comment: Don't have user detail at that point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you cannot use a `const` field. Anything with `const` modifier must be able to be evaluated to a constant at compile time.

What you want is a static field initialised by a static constructor

```
public class YourSurroundingClass {
    private static readonly string CookieName;

    static YourSurroundingClass() {
        CookieName = "TempData" + DateTime.Now.Ticks
            .ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: It will again whenever access will generate new value

Comment: No it won't. Static constructors will only run once. Or do you mean you want it to be constant even if your program restarts? For that you need to write to a file. @Md.ParvezAlam

Answer (score 0):

If you define a variable as `get` only, then you can set it in the constructor of your class but after that it can never be changed.

```
public class MyClass
{
   private string CookieName { get; }

   public MyClass()
   {
      CookieName = "TempData" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
   }
}
```